# Restricting API access on Google APIs not working

Tags: php, google-api, google-search-api, replit

I was recently working on a project using https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/, but when I tried to restrict the API key to my repl.it project website (`search.myreplitusername.repl.co`), it broke the search feature at my repl.it page that depends on the Google API.

After I restricted the API key to `search.myreplitusername.repl.co` or `*.myreplitusername.repl.co` I got this in the console:

```php
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=MY_API_KEY&amp;cx=MY_CX&amp;q=search+query): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
```

Does anyone know why this is happening or how to fix this?